# Making Stretch Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I need to Animate Splash Screen in Android and I'm having a circle in the center of the Screen and I want that to Stretch to fill the entire Screen in an Animated way.How do I make it?

Answer (score 2):

Its call Scale Animation you can do it like that

```
    ScaleAnimation scal=new ScaleAnimation(0, 1f, 0, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
    scal.setDuration(1000);
    scal.setFillAfter(true);
    YOUR_VIEW.setAnimation(scal);
```

**YOUR_VIEW** is the view of your xml(like ImageView) which you want to perform animation.